# Parse.com Push Notification inbox or history in the application

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I am trying to implement into an Android project a Push Notification history or Inbox.  I am using Parse.Com as my push notification provider.  Has anyone been successful at attempting this before?

Comment: What have you tried?... One way is to save the push data in a Parse Object before you send a push, then the inbox is a pretty simple query..

Comment: I was hoping that perhaps they had a separate SDK. I'll just make a table and store the notifications there. Just don't want to add too many requests(per second).

Answer (score 1):

I have had success creating a Push Notification inbox for iOS and Android.

It works something like this:

1. Push is created and sent. Simultaenously create a Notification object.
2. Allow users to go to the inbox via tapping on a push or via a standard UI button.
3. When user opens the push notification inbox, query and show the list of all the Notification objects for that user.